# How can I set format to the end of path in phoenix?

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a phoenix router with this structure:

```
defmodule Hexlet.Router do
  use Hexlet.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug :put_secure_browser_headers
  end

  pipeline :api do
    plug :accepts, ["json"]
  end

  scope "/api", Hexlet do
    pipe_through :api

    resources "/sessions", SessionController, only: [:create, :delete]
  end
end
```

I'm sending AJAX requests from browser to my api. I can reach it by `localhost:4000/api/sessions` but I can't by `localhost:4000/api/sessions.json`. I want to have it vice versa. How can I do that?

I know that rails has this ability by adding `constraints: { format: :json }` to the scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trailing_format_plug ([GitHub](https://github.com/mschae/trailing_format_plug), [Hex](https://hex.pm/packages/trailing_format_plug)) for this.

Add the plug to your endpoint and it should work:

```
defmodule MyApp.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app
  ...
  plug TrailingFormatPlug
  plug MyApp.Router

end
```

Comment: @asiniy Try putting the `TrailingFormatPlug` in `lib/endpoint.ex` before `plug MyApp.Router`